# What's the simplest way to deploy a Grails-generated WAR file?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, grails

I've been having persistent problems (for several weeks) getting Tomcat to deploy a WAR file. I'm looking for a simple server. It does not need to have a lot of functionality-it just needs to be simple to set up. In particular I'm looking for a program that I can just drop a WAR file into and have the enclosed web application launch.

Comment: have you just tried copying the war into the webapps folder? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Numerous errors- everything from folder permissions to log4j errors. I've looked for ways to disable log4j completely and haven't found any site with a straight, simple answer. So I'm looking for any server software that does what it's supposed to right out of the box.

Comment: you need to setup your logging and folder permissions correctly.  I do not know of an 'easy' answer for this.

Comment: IS there any server software that self-configures its own folders and logs?

Comment: would cloudfoundry meet your needs? http://blog.springsource.org/2011/04/12/one-step-deployment-with-grails-and-cloud-foundry/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to give jetty runner a try. It basically just uses an embedded jetty instance to run your war file.

http://blogs.webtide.com/janb/entry/jetty_runner

It is available on Maven and it is in fact how heroku apps built with grails are ran. http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-a-java-web-application-that-launches-with-jetty-runner

Answer (score 3):

If your application does not start on tomcat, it almost certainly means it won't start on any servlet container - containers implement a spec, and are very similar in many aspects.

What you should do is go and hunt each problem one by one, until the application starts. The problem is the app, not the container.

Comment: I used Grails to generate the WAR file. However, Grails does have some known issues. See http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2730. In addition, when I run my Grails application using the command line "grails run-app" it runs properly without error, so my web app isn't bad.

Comment: yes, but that's different. There is always a chance to hit some corner case when running on embedded vs not-embedded. So fix the problems one by one.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a similar problem where my app ran fine with "grails run-app" but not as a war file. It was caused by a missing "package" line in one of the files. I was getting 404 errors. When a war file is unpacked on the server it doesn't put files in the same directory locations as when the are in the grails environment. Not sure this will help you but maybe others with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

if you get a fresh tomcat instance, generate a hellow world app and generate your war file via `grails dev war` it should work without a hitch. typically problems arise form adding dependencies that clash with server libs.

if you want to give other servers a try I would suggest resin as one of the easiest to setup, run and maintain.